# LINQ Where clause throws casting exception from string to Guid even though comparison only contains Guids

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I get the following error when executing a LINQ to SQL statement: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not valid.

The exception occurs on this line:

```
IList<DocumentData> dds = hcDbContext.DocumentDatas.Where(d => fileDataSyncIds.Contains(d.FileDataSyncId)).ToList();
```

`d.FileDataSyncId` is a `Guid` and `fileDataSyncIds` is type `IList<Guid>`.

There's no string so I don't understand where the error is coming from.

This is the code:

```
DocumentData zipFile = new DocumentData();
IList<Guid> fileDataSyncIds = hcDbContext.Documents.Where(d => d.EventId == eventId && d.DocumentOwnerTeamId == teamId).Select(d => d.FileDataSyncId).ToList();
//Exception on next line
IList<DocumentData> dds = hcDbContext.DocumentDatas.Where(d => fileDataSyncIds.Contains(d.FileDataSyncId)).ToList();
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {

        foreach (var dd in dds) {
            var docFile = archive.CreateEntry(dd.Filename);

            using (var entryStream = docFile.Open())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream)) {
                streamWriter.Write(dd.FileData);
            }
        }
    }
    zipFile.Filename = "Event" + eventId.ToString() + "_Team" + teamId + "_Documents.zip";
    zipFile.FileData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

return zipFile;
```

Comment: Check the type of `FileDataSyncId` in `DocumentDatas` table definition, and make sure that it is `Guid`/`uniqueidentifier`, not `String`/`varchar(...)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good catch. It hadn't been updated from `nvarchar(max)` to `uniqueidentifier` in the table. Turn it into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the mapping of the `FileDataSyncId` field of the `DocumentDatas` table. In order for the `Contains` to succeed, the field must be `uniqueidentifier` in the database, and `Guid` on the .NET side. The error message suggests that .NET side sees the field as a `String`, causing the problem.